# What is the best map implementation to use when storing integers with char keys?

Tags: java, char, maps

I have a set of flags which are part of a huge text data file as single characters.
Before processing the file I map each flag to the id of a property it represents.
While processing the file I need to look up these mappings as fast as possible (I do it a lot).

Currently I store these in a HashMap.
And the code looks like this:

```
    private HashMap<Integer, Integer> _propertyKeys;

    private int _getKeyedProperty(char key) {
      return (_propertyKeys.get((int) key));
    }
```

Is there any way I could be doing this faster, using a better implementation of Map than HashMap or even using arrays to prevent boxing/unboxing?

Comment: Well, you could use an array with 65'536 int entries and having your keys as the index of the elements. I guess you can't have less time-overhead than that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [TIntIntHashMap](http://trove4j.sourceforge.net/javadocs/gnu/trove/TIntIntHashMap.html) from GNU Trove. It uses primitives for the keys and values.

I have used the GNU Trove primitive list classes and found that they give a noticeable performance improvement when compared to the standard list classes using autoboxing for primitives.

Comment: Thanks, I love the fact that c# supports primitives as types for all the generic stuff. Pity Java doesn't. By the way your link is to a local JavaDoc :) Sure Google can help me find it though.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the full set of flags that will be used, you can create an Enum of them and use java.util.EnumMap.